# How to set Apache proxy to bypass some hosts & domains

Tags: macos, apache, proxy

**My problem:**

My local Apache project returns ERROR CODE: 504 when talking to a local Java project. The local java project is a REST server, while the Apache project is a user interface.

**The detailed error message:**

Error code: 504 . Reason: ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved. The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://localhost:8080/um-rest/usermanagement/authenticate. Connection to 127.0.0.1 failed. The system returned:(111) Connection refused. The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again. Your cache administrator is servicedesk@niwa.co.nz. Generated Mon, 10 Aug 2015 04:47:41 GMT by www-proxy.niwa.co.nz (squid/2.7.STABLE9)

**I've setup the system's network proxies on my Mac:**

1. ticked checkbox "Auto Proxy Discovery"
2. ticked checkbox "Web Proxy(HTTP)"
3. ticked checkbox "Secure Web Proxy(HTTPS)"
4. filled out "Web Proxy Server" host & port for both HTTP & HTTPS: localhost, 127.0.0.1, localhost:8080, 127.0.0.1:8080

Local Apache has also been set with proxy related Module, like proxy_module in httpd.conf file.

**More clues:**

When I use a browser to visit "http://localhost:8080/um-rest/usermanagement/authenticate" directly, it works. While when I use the apache project to communicate with the java REST server, it returns error. At the end of the whole error message, it says proxy returns this error. For me, it sounds localhost:8080 is still being passed to proxy, which should not happen.

Do I miss some setting of apache proxy, and apache will not use the system's proxy setting? Thanks!

Comment: Please add tags with your operating system to your question, since this appears to be an OSX specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason, it's because my php project has a curl_options(with CURLOPT_PROXY => 'http://www-proxy.niwa.co.nz:80') in code. While I was always thinking it's the setting in Apache Server. So the only thing I need to do is commenting this setting.